# MacOS, Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kiwisolver'

Tags: python, macos, atom-editor

I tried to import kiwisolver in Atom on MacOS Sierra, and I get the error it is not found:

Input:

```
import kiwisolver as kiwi
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Kev/Documents/Uvic/Python/PHYS 321B/A6Q5&6_Coupled_Oscillators_Matrix.py", line 3, in <module>
import kiwisolver as kiwi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kiwisolver'
```

The problem is that it is already installed:

```
w134-87-183-190:~ Kev$ sudo python -m pip install kiwisolver

The directory '/Users/Kev/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Kev/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting kiwisolver
Downloading kiwisolver-1.0.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (110kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 831kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from kiwisolver)
Installing collected packages: kiwisolver
Successfully installed kiwisolver-1.0.1

w134-87-183-190:~ Kev$ sudo python3 -m pip install kiwisolver

The directory '/Users/Kev/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Kev/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from kiwisolver)
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? How do I resolve this issue? I need it to run Matplotlib.

Edit: I'm using Python 3.6.

```
w134-87-183-190:~ Kev$ python -V
Python 2.7.10

w134-87-183-190:~ Kev$ python --version 
Python 2.7.10

w134-87-183-190:~ Kev$ python3 --version 
Python 3.6.4
```

In atom, I have this in my config.cson. All three paths give the same error:

```
runner:
    scopes:
      # python: "/usr/local/bin/python3"
      # python: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python"
      python: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6"
```

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: I installed Python 3.6, which I am using, although MacOS comes with 2.7 supplied by Apple.

Comment: what python is your env using?

Comment: Python 3.6 (I think), since this is the path I gave to Atom: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After 3+ hours of agony, the solution turned out to be quite simple.

Uninstall Kiwisolver:

```
pip3 uninstall kiwisolver
```

Then reinstalling Kiwisolver:

```
pip3 install kiwisolver
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac try running this, as you might have some permission issues:

```
pip3 install kiwisolver --user
```

Comment: It's telling me: 
`Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from kiwisolver)`

Comment: @Kevin Maybe you have installed it for a different user (with sudo, for example)?
Or you have installed it in a local or non-standard package directory?

Comment: I have it installed in: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`