# Trying to import azure.data.tables and getting an error on macOS

Tags: azure-table-storage

I am running

```
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
```

and getting the error below. The package is installed using pip.
Running MACOS.
why do I get the error?

```
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

This can cause **if you have multiples version of python installed**.

Try using `pip3` to install module instead of `pip` **possibly pip install libraries in different dictionary than pip3** does.

```py
pip3 install "modulename"
```

***References:***

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968239/mac-python-import-error-no-module-named-site)

[MacOS, Python: ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522502/macos-python-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-kiwisolver)

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to combine all python version to 1?